# How do handle EF database connections in Azure Functions V2?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am converting a WebJob to Azure Functions.  I am using Azure Functions version 2.  My issue is connecting to my database. The classes inside the Azure Function project do not talk to the database but they do reference classes that do talk to the database.  When I run this as a webjob I simply call the configuationmanager and get the setting for the connectionstring.  I made adjustments to get the string from a different location for Azure Functions but I still get the following error:

*Azure Function The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'*
I put the connection string into the Application Settings:

```
local.settings.json: Values:{"myconnectionstring"..... )
```

I then access this value using this:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myconnectionstring");
```

I can step through the code and see it as expected in the watch window.  That part is figured out.  But what should the connection string actually look like to work. 
The one that looks like the following:

```
 "metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Server=tcp ……………………
```

Or

```
connection string="Server=tcp:somthing.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=myid;
```

Or is there another style to the connection string I need to use for this to work.

Entity Framework 6.2 in the Core classes that do the work (.net 4.6.3)
The Azure Function is .netStandardv2

Comment: if youre using .net 4.6.3 just use azure function v1 ???

Comment: @Thomas I was trying to use v2 because I had issues with v1 when I tried to implement them about 10 months ago.  The issue was I would frequently have to delete the function and start over when deploying a new version because it seemed to keep the old version after publish.  I have switched back to v1. I hope this issue has been resolved.

Comment: check this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions. You can't target .Net 4.6.3 using Azure function v2